# Употребление «вслед за»

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика, предлоги

> «Далеко не всегда на нашем пути встречается педагог, **которого вслед за
>   автором текста** можно назвать любимым человеком».

Это предложение встретилось в сочинении ЕГЭ. Корректно ли такое употребление предлога *вслед за*? Как можно выразить ту же мысль безукоризненно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вроде бы и правильно, да не совсем. Совсем правильно было бы, если бы речь шла о конкретном человеке, которого автор назвал любимым, и мы тоже можем его так назвать "вслед за автором":

"Я встретил педагога Иванова, которого(,) вслед за автором текста(,) можно назвать любимым человеком".

Но Вы-то говорите о встрече с педагогом, которого автор не знал и никак его не называл. Поэтому нужно найти другие слова, например:

**...встречается педагог, которого автор текста назвал бы любимым человеком**;

**...встречается педагог из тех, кого(,) вслед за автором текста(,) можно назвать любимым человеком.**

---

***Дополнение***

Нашел, где Амонашвили пишет про любимого человека ([здесь](https://unotices.com/book.php?id=165086&page=34)):

"Вас уже давно нет в живых, любимый мой человек, но я все хожу по Вашим тропам и ищу разгадку той Святой минуты, названной мною Моментом Педагогической Истины, когда благой учитель свершает ЧУДО".

Если речь об этой педагогической притче Амонашвили, то я бы написал:

**...встречается педагог, которого мы, подобно автору текста, можем назвать любимым человеком**;

**...встречается педагог, которого мы можем назвать любимым человеком, подобно тому, как автор текста называл своего учителя**.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, автор текста описал некоторые качества педагога, которого можно было бы назвать любимым человеком. И утверждается, что встретить такого педагога в реальной жизни можно далеко не всегда. Без контекста предложение "не звучит", и я бы сформулировал его так:

**Далеко не всегда на нашем пути встречается педагог, которого, согласно автору этого текста, можно назвать любимым человеком.**

Я бы ещё заменил "любимого человека" на "любимого учителя", но нельзя, наверное ("вслед за автором текста" :)

Думаю, что сразу после упомянутого текста оригинальное предложение выглядело бы вполне нормально. "Вслед за автором" здесь означает практически то же, что и "согласно автору" в моём варианте.

Comment: Да, там текст Ш. Амонашвили, который был грузином (и "любимый мой человек" в его тексте выглядит очень органично). Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Напомню первое и главное правило редактора (а ведь именно редактированием Вы собираетесь заняться, вопрошая: *"Как можно выразить ту же мысль безукоризненно?")*:

ЕСЛИ **МОЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ**, **НУЖНО НЕ ПРАВИТЬ**, ибо - нет предела совершенству.

> «Далеко не всегда на нашем пути встречается педагог, которого вслед за
>   автором текста можно назвать любимым человеком».

Всё совершенно корректно.

Comment: А разве правильно, что мы говорим о гипотетическом человеке, которого **вслед за автором** можно назвать любимым, хотя автор его так не называл?

Comment: Почему - гипотетическом?! Автор его назвал: это - любимый педагог!

Comment: Автор назвал так Дейду Варо, которой уже давно нет в живых...

Comment: Какая разница для нас? Мы работаем с буковками. Автор назвал педагога (редко встречающегося) любимым человеком. И мы - вслед за  автором - подтвердим: любимый человек + редкий педагог = люблю. Нет, что ж тут туманного? Если б не моя учительница русского и литературы, меня вообще могло не состояться. Потому и повторю вслед за неизвестным мне автором: это огромное счастье, когда педагог, который в силах организовать твою судьбу, любим тобою.